# Setting up MongoDB to work with two data directories

Tags: mongodb

I have a `mongoDb` machine with 1 TB drive (on AWS that is the limit).
however I need to store more than 1 TB of data on this `mongoDB` setup, but it's not heavy on reads / write.

Is there a way to split the data directory to two mounts - two different directories? (instead of using LVM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`directoryperdb`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption--directoryperdb) configuration option so that each database's files are stored in a separate subdirectory, and then use different mount points depending on the volume you want to use.

This option can be helpful in provisioning additional storage or different storage configurations depending on the database usage (i.e. SSD or PIOPS for a database which is more I/O intensive, while using normal EBS storage for archival data).

Important caveats:

- There is a highlighted note in the documentation for  [`directoryperdb`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption--directoryperdb) which shows how to migrate the files for an existing deployment.
- If you separate your data files onto multiple volumes, this may change your [Backup Strategy](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/backups/). In particular, if you are using filesystem/EC2 snapshots to get a consistent backup of a running `mongod` you can no longer do so if the data and/or journal files are on different volumes.

Comment: thanks. not exactly what i was looking for, but i can use it to manage the data on several mongo dbs.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't solved anything like your problem. However I've read about Sharding technique which is defined as:

> Sharding is a method for storing data across multiple machines.
>   MongoDB uses sharding to support deployments with very large data sets
>   and high throughput operations.

It sounds promissing for your problem. Wanna try? [Sharding MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-introduction/)

(sorry, not enough rep for commenting)

Comment: I'm familiar with Sharding, but since we are not heavy on reads / writes - it seems kinda weird to add machines (more cpu, ram, etc).